# What type to use to store a single char in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, char

I am writing a function which is meant to take a character as an argument and return a character. Using String for this looks a bit strange for me. Should I, or there is something like a char type in Scala 2.8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Java    Scala
----    -----
boolean Boolean
byte    Byte
char    Char
int     Int
long    Long
float   Float
double  Double

String  String
```

I sense a pattern...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a character type in scala. It's called `Char`.

Scala also has character literals which are written by surrounding the character with single quotes like in most languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only expecting Basic Multilingual Plane characters, use `Char`. Otherwise, you'll need to use `Int`. See [the JavaDoc for the Character class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and [this technical article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/Supplementary/) for a discussion of this.